# Python multiprocessing gives slower speed as more cores are used

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, sparse-matrix

I'm using Python Multiprocessing module to diagonalize a (large and sparse) matrix multiple times. I have to do this for a thousand times, so decided to do it in multiprocessing as I have 24 cores.

The code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
from scipy import sparse

def diag(param):
    wf, vf = 0, 0
    for i in range(10000):
        num = np.random.rand()
        .... # unrelated code producing the matrix with param and num

        Mat = sparse.csc_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(8000, 8000))
        w, v = eigsh(Mat, k=12)

        .... #some other unrelated process updating wf and vf using w and v


    return wf, vf

def Final(temp):
    print("Process " % multiprocessing.current_process().name)
    print(temp)
    np.random.seed()
    w0, v0 = diag(temp)
    
    .... #unrelated process using w0 and v0 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(Final, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

Other parts of the code are irrelevant, as diagonalising a 8000 by 8000 sparse matrix is the rate determining step in my case.

The process worked well when I did not use multiprocessing. However, the speed when I implement multiprocessing is now inversely proportional to the number of cores used(!!). I'll be grateful for any input on this, as I understand pool in general does make your process (a tiny bit) slower, but not by this much. I'm very confused as scipy inherently does not have multiprocessing implemented.

Example. Normally in one core, 10 diagonalizations take around 2s. In 24 cores (in the example above 10 cores!), it will take ~40s.

Edit: As a context, the matrix is very sparse - only 48000 entries in 8000 by 8000 matrix.

---

Edit: Solved, but still remaining questions.

I've solved the issue, and it is very interesting and I want your input.

The issue was as follows: When scipy.sparse diagonalises a matrix bigger than some threshold, then it automatically multithreads (which I checked with top.). However, this does NOT increase the speed significantly compared to using a single core case.

I checked the performance with my own laptop (dual core, nothing fancy!), and the performance was better(!) than the 24 core output (which has slightly bigger number of flops, but still.) and realised that the automatic multithreading is not doing anything, but just building up the queue and blocking multiprocessing.

Therefore, the solution was to set MKL and BLAS to single thread using os and then multithread - of which the programme runs very well now. I'm now curious, as why does BLAS multithread on the first place, but do not utilise the multithreads at all - it might be a developer issue, but there might be another convoluted solution. Who knows!

Comment: Multiprocessing means copying data and aggregating it when you're done. That's going to have an impact. It's not magical free time.

Comment: Serializing `wf` and `vf` will add overhead, but you are parallelizing so you're getting some of that back. I don't know how you're getting data into your forked processes - that might also be slowing you down. If you're out of memory with 10 copies of your matrix and you have to swap I'd expect a massive performance hit (like you're seeing). I wouldn't expect your example code to run that much slower but the devil is in the details that aren't included.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I wrote a dummy code which only involves matrix diagonalization. Unfortunately, the problem persists. The eigsh code is the culprit for gobbling up all the time. My first guess is it *might* be GIL, but considering Multiprocess is there to exactly avoid this problem puzzles me....

Comment: _nod_, GIL isn't a likely guess here, because as you say, it's exactly what multiprocessing is there to prevent. What _is_ likely is serialization/deserializing when moving between processes. As Mad Physicist said, multiprocessing is only valuable when your computation is so expensive that the cost of performing it overwhelms the costs of moving the data around (so the bigger and more unwieldy the data is, the more you pay to parallelize).

Comment: ...you might want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html, as a way to make passing data around cheaper; there's a numpy example right there in the documentation.

Comment: That said, if scipy implements multithreading in C for the calculation you're trying to perform, using multiprocessing is pure loss; it makes things worse only and never better, because multithreading avoids needing to copy data between process images _at all_, and code written in a C module can release the GIL while it works, so when you start using multiprocessing in addition you have each process starting up its own group of threads (which then compete with each other for CPU), _and_ you have all the overhead required to copy content around..

Comment: Thanks for this! Will there be any way it can run on multiple cores in parallel? I need 1000 data points and each data point involves 10^5 diagonalizations. If Multiprocessing is not for this, then can there be some other fixes available?

I don't know if BLAS is there for eigsh, but I'm not sure how it'll affect it. Another code of mine has a very large matrix multiplication (@) for a sparse matrix involved (which I know is BLASed) and for this multiprocessing works like a charm. It might be specific to eigsh, but a mystery for now.

Comment: I would suggest exploring the MKL eigensolvers - it's pretty well-optimized and it'll run threaded no problem. Calling C functions from within python is, of course, a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue by adding following lines

```
import os
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```